# How to run a script on startup using Screen on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, scripts, screen, startup

Trying to find out how to run this command upon startup of Ubuntu:

```
su - username -c "screen -dm -S autorunner ~/Desktop/..."
```

This command is based off of a [guide](https://coderwall.com/p/quflrg/run-a-script-on-startup-in-a-detached-screen-on-a-raspberry-pi) for the Raspbian and uses rc.local. I have tried to find anything more up to date describing alternatives to using rc.local for a screen script on startup and have not found anything relevant to 20.04.

Comment: One way: Look up how to write a simple systemd service. rc.local comes from sysvinit, which Ubuntu stopped using many years ago. Use of `screen` sometimes indicates a design problem: Services should usually run as a different user, and properly-written services  shouldn't need screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'password_username' | sudo -S su - username -c "screen -dm -S autorunner /home/username/Desktop/..."
exit 0
```